# How to insert numerous data into temporary table?

Tags: t-sql, insert, bulk

I'm building a program which generates a T-SQL query in following form:

```
DECLARE @In TABLE (Col CHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @In VALUES value1, value2... value1000
GO
INSERT INTO @In VALUES value1001, value1002...
```

but the second `INSERT` statement throws error:

> Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
>   Must declare the table variable "@In".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are adding the `GO` batch separator, so the table variable doesn't exist on the second `INSERT`

Comment: How can I insert more than 1000 values without using `GO` separator?

Comment: either using the way the answer tells you or using `INSERT INTO @In SELECT columns FROM SomeTableWith1000Values`

Comment: @WaldemarGałęzinowski Why do you think you need a `GO` batch separator?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `VALUES (...), (...)`:

```
INSERT INTO table(colA, colN, ...) VALUES
    (col1A, col1B, ...)
    , ...
    , (colnA, colnB, ...)
```

With @In:

```
DECLARE @In TABLE (Col CHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @In VALUES 
    ('value1')
    , ('value2')
    , ...
    , ('value1000')
```

It will insert X rows all at once. GO is not needed. Variables declared before `GO` don't exist anymore after `GO`.

Answer (score 3):

Simplistically, the `GO` batch separator should be removed (as stated in @Julien's answer).

Just prove that it does work, try the following:

```sql
DECLARE @ValuesPerInsert INT = 1000; -- 1000 works, 1001 fails
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
DECLARE @In TABLE (Col CHAR(20))';

;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT    TOP (3523)
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [Num],
          (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) % @ValuesPerInsert) AS [Position]
  FROM  [master].[sys].[all_columns]
) -- select * from cte
SELECT @SQL += CASE cte.[Position]
                  WHEN 1 THEN N';' + NCHAR(0x0D) + NCHAR(0x0A)
                              + N'INSERT INTO @In (Col) VALUES (''Val-'
                              + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), cte.[Num]) + N''')'
                  ELSE ', (''Val-' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), cte.[Num]) + N''')'
               END
FROM   cte;

SET @SQL += ';
';

SELECT CONVERT(XML, N'<sql>' + @SQL + N'</sql>') AS [@SQL];

EXEC (@SQL);
GO
```

That produces the following SQL:

```sql
DECLARE @In TABLE (Col CHAR(20));
INSERT INTO @In (Col) VALUES ('Val-1'), ('Val-2'), ('Val-3'), ('Val-4'), ..., ('Val-1000');
INSERT INTO @In (Col) VALUES ('Val-1001'), ('Val-1002'), ('Val-1003'), ..., ('Val-2000');
INSERT INTO @In (Col) VALUES ('Val-2001'), ('Val-2002'), ('Val-2003'), ..., ('Val-3000');
INSERT INTO @In (Col) VALUES ('Val-3001'), ('Val-3002'), ('Val-3003'), ..., ('Val-3523');
```

And you will see in the "Messages" tab:

```
(1000 row(s) affected)

(1000 row(s) affected)

(1000 row(s) affected)

(523 row(s) affected)
```

Of course, there is a 1000 value maximum when using the `VALUES` list. If you try to do 1001 rows per `INSERT`, you will get the following error:

> Msg 10738, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   The number of row value expressions in the INSERT statement exceeds the maximum allowed number of 1000 row values.

That being said, if you want to insert more than 1000 rows per `INSERT` statement, you can use the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` construct and combine each row with a `UNION ALL`:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
DECLARE @In TABLE (Col CHAR(20));
';

;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT    TOP (3523)
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [Num]
  FROM  [master].[sys].[all_columns]
) -- select * from cte
SELECT @SQL += CASE cte.[Num]
                  WHEN 1 THEN N'INSERT INTO @In (Col)' + NCHAR(0x0D) + NCHAR(0x0A)
                              + N'  SELECT ''Val-1'''
                  ELSE NCHAR(0x0D) + NCHAR(0x0A) + N'  UNION ALL'
                       + NCHAR(0x0D) + NCHAR(0x0A) + N'  SELECT ''Val-'
                       + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), cte.[Num]) + N''''
               END
FROM   cte;

SET @SQL += ';
';

SELECT CONVERT(XML, N'<sql>' + @SQL + N'</sql>') AS [@SQL];

EXEC (@SQL);
GO
```

That produces the following SQL:

```sql
DECLARE @In TABLE (Col CHAR(20));
INSERT INTO @In (Col)
  SELECT 'Val-1'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Val-2'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Val-3'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Val-4'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Val-5'
  ...
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Val-3522'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Val-3523';
```

And you will see in the "Messages" tab:

```
(3523 row(s) affected)
```

But I wouldn't go much above 4500 rows in one statement: you want to avoid lock escalation which locks the entire table (well, unless the table is partitioned *and* the option to escalate by locking the partition instead of the table is enabled), and that occurs at about 5000 locks.

And *that* being said, since you are generating this from app code, depending on why you are generating `INSERT` statements in the first place, you might be able to change your approach and use a Table-Valued Paramater (TVP) instead. Using a TVP would allow you to stream the data from the app directly into a query or Stored Procedure as a Table Variable, in which case you would simply do:

```sql
INSERT INTO SchemaName.RealTable (Col)
  SELECT tmp.Col
  FROM   @TVPvariable;
```

But if you need a portable deployment script, then that really isn't an option.